# Can't log-in to GitLab in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gitlab

I'm on Linux Mint 18. I have downloaded the plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7975-gitlab-projects), installed it on IntelliJ, grab API key from GitLab, filled settings with that info:

Server URL: https://gitlab.com/

API Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx

then I go to File > New > Project from Version Control > GitLab
tryied to connect but says:
"cannot log-in to GitLab Server with provided Token"

Answer (score 0):

Can you clone the project using command-line git?

You could report the issue to the plugin developer at https://github.com/PavlikPolivka/GitLabProjects/issues

BTW, there is a request to add native support to IDEA - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109294

Comment: Thank you Dmitriy for replying. Yes I can clone my repo. I have tried in a different way and made it work. Still can't create a gitlab project as I asked, but if I clone my project, open it in IDEA and push a change it work fine.